# Screen blanking near end of Kubuntu installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, kubuntu

I was just installing Kununtu 21.10 on my Dell Inspiron laptop. Near the end of the installation the screen went blank. Obviously, a blank screen gives you no clues. Based on my experience with previous installations, I knew more or less what should have happened: A screen would appear telling me that the installation was successful and to press Enter, click OK, or something like that. Then after some whirring of gears I would be asked to remove the installation medium and press Enter. Then the newly installed system would start.

But faced with that blank screen, I didn't know what to do. I tried Enter, Escape, space, and a few other things. Nothing I tried produced a reaction. So I removed the USB stick I had booted from and did a  hardware restart. That didn't work, so I'm posting this message before I experiment further.

I have two questions.

First, what should I have done about that blank screen? I know what caused it: a timeout since I hadn't pressed any keys recently. But that doesn't tell me what to do about it.

Second, what is achieved by that extra step before removing the boot medium? I understand why it's necessary for the installer to ask the user to press Enter after removing the boot medium, since that prevents the new system from rebooting and starting the installation all over again. But the extra step seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: I can only give *opinion*; if I get strange behavior on a QA-test install (*where I install most*) I usually switch to text terminal & try and get clues... The Ctrl+Alt+F4 (or other) attempt also reveals clues; though on some boxes I'm hitting numerous Fn keys (F1, F2, F7, F8 etc...)  On some boxes there is a *looong* delay before 'enter to eject' (*message on occasion doesn't appear on some hardware too*) but if kernel isn't in final stages of shutdown I can usually login to text terminal & explore..  Last resort I use SysRq keys; alas most are disabled on *impish* (21.10) & *jammy*..

Comment: How would you switch the install of Kubutu 21.10 to a text terminal?  The only way I know of to do the install is to boot from the installation medium (like a USB stick). That gives you the choice of installing with safe graphics or not--nothing about terminal mode.

Comment: I meant using Ctrl+Alt+F4 to switch to a text terminal.  I grabbed a Kubuntu thumb-drive (*just now*) and started an install, then used those keys to switch to text terminal which allows me to explore if things go wrong (*as I'm involved with QA-testing; problems do occur on occasion more than for released products*); my thumb-drive it turns out has 20.04.4 on it (*the next ISO release*) but it'd be the same for any release (*I expected jammy on the thumb-drive actually*).